# Java: What happens if a UDP packet arrives in-between calls to socket.receive()?

Tags: java, udp, buffer, datagram

For my networked Java application, I wrote a thread-safe, non-blocking i/o wrapper over the system-level DatagramSocket. However, I'm confused about something. What happens if a new packet comes in while `callback.onDataReceived()` is executing? Is the packet dropped? Is it added to an OS-level queue and "received" on the next iteration of the loop? If so, does that queue have a maximum size?

```
    /*
     * Receiving thread
     */
    rxThread = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            byte[] incomingBuffer = new byte[DataConstants.NUM_BYTES_IN_DATAGRAM_PACKET_BUF];

            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
            {
                DatagramPacket incomingPacket = new DatagramPacket(incomingBuffer, incomingBuffer.length);
                try
                {
                    basicSocket.receive(incomingPacket);

                    callback.onDataReceived(
                            DatatypeUtil.getNBytes(incomingPacket.getData(), incomingPacket.getLength()),
                            incomingPacket.getAddress());
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct about the OS level buffering that occurs, you can manipulate the size of the buffers using the API methods [DatagramSocket.setRecieveBufferSize()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#setReceiveBufferSize(int)) and [DatagramSocket.getRecieveBufferSize()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#getReceiveBufferSize()) .

**But**

It is also possible to lose some packets as your UDP packets may get dropped  if the buffer overflows or if the packets get lost in transit. After all UDP is a connectionless protocol. If you do need to make sure that all your packets are safe and intact you could switch over to TCP.

Coming back to your question, if it so happens that `callback.onDataReceived()` takes a little longer to execute, the sender is pumping packets and your UDP buffers get full, then you might start losing packets

Comment: Thanks, exactly the answer I was looking for! As for UDP packets possibly getting lost in transit, yeah that's fine. In this specific application, only "commands" need to make it to the other end, all the other data sent can have dropped packets without issue. For commands, I've implemented a system where the sender will re-transmit the command until the receiver sends it back with the 'ack' flag set.

Comment: @AndroidDev if you're going to send ack's, then you might as well opt for a dedicated TCP commands link instead of using UDP, but again as you feel fit.